# How to close a thread from another one when it may not have been initialized

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to implement `Linux pipe operator |`  using java. The basic idea is assigning connected `PipedInputStream` and `PipeOutputStream` to the two commands and they can perform their actions simultaneously.
The implementation is as follows:

```
PipedOutputStream pOutputStream = new PipedOutputStream();
PipedInputStream pInputStream = new PipedInputStream();
pOutputStream.connect(pInputStream);
Thread thread1, thread2;
     thread1 = new Thread(){
       public void run() {
         try {
             new Call(pipe.cmd1).eval(CommandHandler.this, inputStream, pOutputStream);
             pOutputStream.close();
         } catch (Exception e) {
             thread2.interrupt(); // cannot do this as it may not have been initialized
         }
       }
     };
      thread2 = new Thread() {
         public void run() {
            try{
                new Pipe(pipe.cmd2).eval(CommandHandler.this, pInputStream, outputStream);
                // pInputStream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
               // kill the first thread when the second one raises an exception
               thread1.interrupt();
               throw e;
            }
         }
      };

     thread1.start();
     thread2.start();
                        
     // waiting for the two threads to die before carry on
     thread2.join();
     thread1.join();
```

I would like to interrupt the second thread when the first one raises an exception, just like what I did in `thread2 catch`. The problem is `thread2` is assigned latter so I cannot access it within thread1. I tried to inialize `thread1&2` with null values but then they have to be final since they are in an enclosing scope.

Forgive me if it is a stupid question, I just get started to explore multi-threading in java.

** UPDATE **

Thanks to Phil's suggestions. I changed the two anonymous inner classes to two inner classes that extends `Thread`.

```
    class Thread1 extends Thread{
                        public Thread counterThread;
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                new Call(pipe.cmd1).eval(CommandHandler.this, inputStream, pOutputStream);
                                pOutputStream.close();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                // kill thread 2
                                if (counterThread != null) counterThread.interrupt();
                            }
                        }

                        public void setThread(Thread thread) {
                            counterThread = thread;
                        }
                    };
    class Thread2 extends Thread {
                        public Thread counterThread;
                        public void run() {
                            try{
                                new Pipe(pipe.cmd2).eval(CommandHandler.this, pInputStream, outputStream);
                                // pInputStream.close();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                // kill the first thread when the second one raises an exception
                                if (counterThread != null) counterThread.interrupt();
                                throw e;
                            }
                        }
                        public void setThread(Thread thread) {
                            counterThread = thread;
                        }

                    };
                    
                    Thread1 thread1 = new Thread1();
                    Thread2 thread2 = new Thread2();
                    thread1.setThread(thread2);
                    thread2.setThread(thread1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the code you've started with, two possibilities come to mind. There may be better ideas, but here they are:

(1) Add an additional public method in your anonymous inner class definition that allows you to store a reference to an external thread to be messaged/interrupted. After you create both threads, store a reference of each in the other.

(2) Store a reference to a class (possible the same class that creates and launches the threads) that will hold references to each thread. Have the `catch` method call a method in that launching class that will message (via loose coupling pattern) or interrupt the counterpart.

Comment: Thanks to the suggestions! I applied the first advice by making a change to the structures. The two anonymous classes are both in the type of `Thread`, so an additional public method can not be accessed from them. I created two inner classes that extend `Thread` to solve this issue and they work as expected now. I have updated the answer with the new implementation. Thanks again for the answer!